# SSE4 memory compare with difference position

Tags: c++, optimization, sse

My own implementation bite me back when trying to optimize following with SSE4:

```
std::distance(byteptr, std::mismatch(byteptr, ptr + lenght, dataptr).first)
```

This compares the byteptr and data and returns the index where bytes mismatch.
I really do need the raw speed because I'm processing so much memory the RAM speed is already a bottleneck. Fetching and comparing 16 bytes at time with SSE4 would provide a speed boost since comparing 16 bytes at time is faster.

Here is my current code that I could not get working.
It uses GCC SSE intrinsics and needs SSE4.2:

```
// define SIMD 128-bit type of bytes.
typedef char v128i __attribute__ ((vector_size(16)));
// mask of four low bits set.
const uintptr_t aligned_16_imask = (uintptr_t)15;
// mask of four low bits unset.
const uintptr_t aligned_16_mask = ~aligned_16_imask;

inline unsigned int cmp_16b_sse4(v128i *a, v128i *b) {
    return __builtin_ia32_pcmpistri128(__builtin_ia32_lddqu((char*)a), *b, 0x18);  
}

size_t memcmp_pos(const char * ptr1, const char * ptr2, size_t lenght)
{
    size_t nro = 0;
    size_t cmpsz;
    size_t alignlen = lenght & aligned_16_mask;
    // process 16-bytes at time.
    while(nro < alignlen) {
        cmpsz = cmp_16b_sse4((v128i*)ptr1, (v128i*)ptr2);
        ptr1 += cmpsz;
        ptr2 += cmpsz;
        nro += cmpsz;
        // if compare failed return now.
        if(cmpsz < 16)
            return nro;
        if(cmpsz != 16)
            break;
    }
    // process remainder 15 bytes:
    while( *ptr1 == *ptr2 && nro < lenght) {
        ++nro;
        ++ptr1;
        ++ptr2;
    }
    return nro;
}
```

When testing the above function it works most of the time but in some cases it fails.

Comment: What do you mean by 'it fails'? Crash, false positives/negatives...?

Comment: SSE code above produces different results than std::mismatch based one.

Comment: I found out what I did wrong: the code should have used `pcmpestri` instead because `pcmpistri` actualy tries to handle null bytes. My input data is unstructured bits by nature so this broke the code.

Answer (score 2):

One known problem with `pcmpistri` is that it always reads the full 16 bytes - even beyond the end of the variable. This becomes a problem on a page boundary, on the border of allocated to unallocated memory. See [here (scroll down to "Renat Saifutdinov")](https://www.strchr.com/strcmp_and_strlen_using_sse_4.2).

This can be avoided by using only aligned reads of the source even if unaligned reads are supported, [see this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24337096/1305969).

This could be one of the possibilities why your code fails.

Comment: I think the code doesn't suffer either of these problems. For the 16-bytes per round loop I have `lenght & aligned_16_mask` which rounds number of bytes to be processed in first loop to multiple of 16.